# Find images in a Linux directory based on their resolution

Tags: linux, bash, images, resolution, search

I would like to scan all images in a linux directory (recursively within sub-folders), and find those with resolution higher than a specific threshold (e.g. say those with resolutions at least `800x600` or if easier, say with width higher than `1000` pixels). Then I would like to log their address in a `.txt` file, accompanying their resolution (or `[width], [height]` for a better formatting).

How can I do that that in bash script? I have to scan millions of images.

Comment: See: [Fast way to get image dimensions (not filesize)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4670013/3776858)

Comment: also asked on askubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/q/1048914/10127

Comment: [*Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310) – No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below bash script—which uses [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/)’s [`identify`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php) utility—will recursively search the specified directory for all files that end with `.jpg`, `.jpeg`, `.png` and `.gif` and then searches through those for images that report being over 800 x 600.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z $1]; then
  echo -e $0 '[path to search]\nRecursively search the specified directory for images over 800x600'

else

  find $1 \( -iname "*.jpg" -o -iname "*.jpeg" -o -iname "*.png" -o -iname "*.gif" \) -type f -exec identify -format '%w %h %i' '{}' \; | awk '$1>800 || $2>600'

fi
```